Unable to write Spring AOP logic before a method call so that based on AOP method response actual method will invoke
Below Spring boot controller method should execute based on the value returns from another AOP method
@PostMapping("/test/v1/managemtn/updatecase")   
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> updateData(@RequestBody UpdateCase dto) throws UnAuthorisedException {       
  return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}

If below method return true then only above method will invoke. I can't call below method directly because of different reason
public Boolean ifSessinIsValid(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
  final String sessionFlag = commonUtil.sessionFlag;
  GenericResponse tokenStatus;
  if (TRUE.equalsIgnoreCase(sessionFlag)) {
    tokenStatus = loginService.getSessionTokenStatus();
    if (VALID.equalsIgnoreCase(tokenStatus.getStatus())) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    } // enter code here
  }
  return false;
}


I do not understand your question, and there is no AOP anywhere here. Please improve the question and ideally provide a minimal reproducer on GitHub. Otherwise, the question just attracts close votes.
